# Prevent multiple jQuery UI dialogs from displaying

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Whenever I click on any of the links generated it opens the dialog for each link instead of just for the one clicked. I know I must be looking at this completely backwards. How would I go about ensuring that only the dialog for the link clicked is displayed?

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: mkadv,
    contentType: 'application/xml',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'xml',
    complete: function (jsXHR, textStatus) {
        var xmlResponse = $.parseXML(jsXHR.responseText);
        $xml = $(xmlResponse);
        $xml.find('contentItem').each(function () {
            $name = $(this).find('name');
            $link = $(this).find('link');
            $('.mkadv').append('<p><a href="' + $link.text() + '" target="_blank" class="adv" title="' + $name.text() + '">' + $name.text() + '</a></p>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: $link.text(),
                contentType: 'application/xml',
                async: true,
                dataType: 'xml',
                complete: function (jsXHR, textStatus) {
                    var xmlResponse = $.parseXML(jsXHR.responseText);
                    $xml = $(xmlResponse);
                    $xml.find('advisory').each(function () {
                        $advisory = $(this).find('advisoryText');
                    })

                    $('.adv').each(function () {
                        var $alink = $(this);
                        var $dialog = $('<div>' + $advisory.text() + '</div>').dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            width: 550,
                            title: $alink.attr('title'),
                            beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                                $("body").css({
                                    overflow: 'inherit'
                                })
                            },

                            open: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).scrollTop("0");
                                $("body").css({
                                    overflow: 'hidden'
                                })
                            },
                            buttons: [
                            {
                                text: "Ok",
                                click: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            }
                            ]
                        });

                        $alink.click(function () {
                            $dialog.dialog('open');
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                },

                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log("Error is" + request.responseText + " " + status + " " + error);
                }
            });
        })
    },

    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log("Error is" + request.responseText + " " + status + " " + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I tried but I can't seem to get it to recognize the xml for each call.

Comment: It's bit hard to read but looks like you're iterating through contentItem, creating a link, then for each response binding to link click. Is it possible you're biding to the same click in each iteration?

Comment: That is entirely possible and I had thought the same thing. I'm not 100% sure how to go about fixing that if so. each contentItem and advisory has a unique id in the xml as well, I had gone and applied that to not only the link created but the dialog being generated thinking that I could tie them together somehow, but I ended up with the same results.

Comment: Moving the $('.adv').each call out of the second ajax and at the tail end of the first ajax call, solves the multiple dialog displays but I lose the variable information for the advisory.text(), even tried to place it in a global, still returning undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake after many sessions of trial and error, but I suppose that is how one learns. Turns out trying to accomplish everything inside of one, or even nested, ajax calls makes things not work properly.

So after some research and more trail and error, I figured what I really needed was some callback functions to get that data out of the ajax call and into a function that I could actually work with.

I'm sure this isn't ideal and there is probably a way to refine this even better but here is my end result in hopes that it helps someone else with a similar problem.

```
function getAdvisories(myLink, callback) {

jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: myLink,
   contentType: 'application/xml',
   async: true,
   dataType: 'xml',
   complete: function ( jsXHR, textStatus, advisory ) {
       var xmlResponse = $.parseXML(jsXHR.responseText);
       callback(xmlResponse);    
   },
   error: function(request, status, error) {
       console.log("Error is" + request.responseText + " " + status + " " + error);
   }                      
});
}

function getAdvText(alink, callback) {
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: alink,
   contentType: 'application/xml',
   async: true,
   dataType: 'xml',
   complete: function ( jsXHR, textStatus ) {
       var xmlResponse = $.parseXML(jsXHR.responseText);
       $xml = $(xmlResponse);
       advisory = $xml.find('advisoryText').text();
       callback(advisory);
   },
   error: function(request, status, error) {
       console.log("Error is" + request.responseText + " " + status + " " + error)
   }                      
});
}

getAdvisories(mkadv, function(xml) {
$xml = $(xml);
$xml.find('contentItem').each(function(i) {
            $name = $(this).find('name');
            $link = $(this).find('link');
            id = $(this).find('id').text();
            var name = $name.text();
            var name = name.replace(/[^A-Za-z\-]/g, " ");
            $('.mkadv').append('<p><a href="'+$link.text()+'" id="'+id+'" class="adv" title="'+name+'">'+$name.text()+'</a></p>');
            setAdvDialog(id, $link, advisory);
})
});

function setAdvDialog(id, $link, advisory) {

getAdvText($link.text(), function(advtxt) {
            advisory = advtxt;
            var $alink = $('#'+id+'');
            var $dialog = $('<div>'+advisory+'</div>').dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            width: 550,
                            title: $alink.attr('title'),
                            beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
                                     $("body").css({ overflow: 'inherit' })
                            },
                            open: function(event, ui) {
                                     $(this).scrollTop("0");
                                     $("body").css({ overflow: 'hidden' })
                            },
                            buttons: [
                                      {
                                         text: "Ok",
                                         click: function() {
                                         $(this).dialog("close");
                                      }
                            }
            ]
            });
            $alink.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
});
}
```